# How do I properly initialize bulleted list in bitbucket markdown

Tags: bitbucket, markdown

I have some markdown in a README.md that looks like this:

```
# Tool

## General Info

This is a python tool that provides an interface to Kirby flash memories. 

Tool functionality includes:
*  Item 1
*  Item 2
*  Item 3
    *  Item 3a
    *  Item 3b
    *  Item 3c
```

But the result in my Bitbucket repo looks like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add empty line after `Tool functionality includes:` so that it would be

```
# Tool

## General Info

This is a python tool that provides an interface to Kirby flash memories. 

Tool functionality includes:

*  Item 1
*  Item 2
*  Item 3
    *  Item 3a
    *  Item 3b
    *  Item 3c
```

Comment: @PeterKapteyn nice! a general advice for any markdown: if anything is going wrong start your troubleshooting with separating blocks with empty lines.